# Boost Python Expose overloaded member functions returning pointer to class object

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have this setup and want to port it to python :

```
class A {
    public:
        A() {}
        A(string name): name_(name) {}
        ~A() {
            for (auto it = mymap_.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it) {
                delete it->second;
            }
        }
        string name() const { 
            return name_; 
        }
        bool has_a(string name) const {
            return (mymap_.find(name) != mymap_.end());
        }
        A* a(string name) {
            if (has_a(name)) {
                return mymap_.at(name);
            }
            return nullptr;
        }
        const A* a(string name) const {
            if (has_a(name)) {
                return mymap_.at(name);
            }
            return nullptr;
        }
        //Owns pointer
        bool AddA(A* a) {
            if (a && !has_a(a->name())) {
                mymap_.insert(make_pair(a->name(), a));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    private:
        string name_;
        map<string, A*. mymap_;
};
```

I want to expose overloaded function a() for both const and non const pointers whose ownership should not be passed to python.

```
void add_a(A& a, std::unique_ptr<A>& ap) {
    a.AddA(ap.get()); ap.release();
}
A* (A::*mutable_a)(string) = &A::a;
const A* (A::*immutable_a)(string) const = &A::a;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyModule) {
   class_<A, boost::nocopyable, boost::shared_ptr<A> >("A", init<string>())
       .def(init<>())
       .def("name", &A::name)
       .def("has_a", &A::has_a)
       .def("a", mutable_a, return_value_policy<copy_non_const_reference>())
       .def("const_a", immutable_a, return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>())
       .def("add_a", add_a, with_custodian_and_ward<1,2>())
   ;
}
```

It seems to work if return value policy for `"a()"` and `"const_a()"` is `return_value_policy<reference_existing_object`, `with_custodian_and_ward_postcall<1,0> >()` but not in current setup. Problem with this being that object extracted using `const_a()` is also mutable in python and it is undesirable.

Error I receive on compilation is :

> error: no match for call to _(const
>   boost::python::detail::copy_non_const_reference_expects_a_non_const_reference_return_type

Is there a way to expose this function in python correctly ? I cannot make changes to the base class but I can add some small wrappers like add_a() if that helps me achieve end goal.